# Using NSWorkspace openURL to launch helper app in sandbox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is using `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"helperapp://open"]]` a valid way to launch a helper app from inside the (Mac App Store required) OS X sandbox?

I have tried using `NSWorkspace launchApplication`, however I cannot get it working. According to posts on the Apple Dev Forums it should work, but I have yet to see an example.

Using openURL works for me, and adds the advantage of being able to pass other parameters through the URL.

My only concerns are speed, reliability, and Mac App Store submission.

Does anyone have experience with this, or any pointers?